# Press enter key in a shell script and ignore nohup output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a basic shell script that I made for deploying my packages...

I am facing 2 issues while executing the command

`nohup /home/username/wildfly/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh &`

Its keeping me frozen and saying the below

`nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout`

If I run this command in a normal way, I should press ENTER and the process will keep running in background fine.
So, my question is there any way to simulate that ENTER key stroke?

I have also an `scp` command to copy a file to another server and it's required to enter password after executing it, is there a way to enter the password through `myscript.sh` and press ENTER key?

`scp /home/username/myfile.war 0.0.0.0:/home/username/myfile.war`

***Thanks in advance :)***

Comment: You can't interact with a backgrounded process.  You could conceivably use `expect` to take care of the interaction, but storing passwords and whatnot in the clear for that purpose is always a poor choice. For `scp` consider using an ssh-keypair, possibly in conjunction with a `forced_command` ...

Comment: Could you do something like `printf '\n' | nohup /home/username/wildfly/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh &` to simulate pressing ENTER?

Comment: as mentioned in previous comment you need tools like [tag:expect] for a general solution for this kind of requirement. for shell scripts, take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't actually freeze you, just look confusing because it has the "nohup:" message *after* the prompt for your next command (and then you need to press enter to get a new prompt). But you should be able to avoid the message by redirecting stdout and stderr yourself:

```
nohup /home/username/wildfly/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This sends both stdout and stderr to /dev/null, so `nohup` doesn't have to deal with them.

Comment: Thank you for this, it solved the first part, and for the SCP command to another server, I will do it with a ssh-keypair. 
Please add this to your answer thus it will include the full solution and I will mark it as the right one.